# When Using Throne room on a Throne room do you need two more action cards already in hand?

Tags: dominion

In the base game Dominion, Throne Room lets you play an action card twice.
The Dominon complete reference guide on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/131854/complete-rules-dominion-and-all-its-expansions) singles out the Throne room on a Throne room play for some helpful notes.

> When you play Throne Room on Throne Room, this will let you play two other cards (each twice).

What I'm not clear on is if you need to have both "other" cards in hand already to be able to do this, or can the first card played allow me to draw the card I use on the 2nd Throne room?

Is this acceptable?

**Hand**: Throne Room, Throne Room, Moat, Copper, Copper 
**Play**: Throne Room, Throne Room, Moat (drawing 4), Play Laboratory (which I've just drawn using the Moat), etc...

Or do I have to have the action card already in hand to make use of the "third" Throne Room created by duplicating the second card played?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Dominion, the general rule is that you have to do everything on a card *in order* before you can play another card.

This affects Throne Room in an odd way, because it means you have to do everything printed on the card Throne Room tells you to play, then do everything on that card again.

Thus, when you Throne Room a Throne Room, you play one card and resolve it twice, then play a second card and resolve it twice.

TL;DR Yes, you can play the Laboratory you drew with the Moat as the second Throne Room's second play.

Comment: Incidentally, this is even more complicated with King's Court from the Prosperity set as that card has you play an action 3 times.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the post and it's not relevant to Throne Room, but it *is* relevant to the "in order" part: "+1 Action" just means that your maximum number of actions this turn increases by 1, not to immediately play another action card.

Answer (score 2):

In Dominion, you can play a card instructing you to do something impossible; you just fail to do it and the game continues. So yes, you absolutely can.

More generally, you don't need to anticipate every game state that might happen if you play a card...in many cases, this is impossible anyway. You just need to follow the directions of the card, and skip instructions you can't follow.